# sqlalchemy: обновление сразу нескольких записей

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, orm, sqlalchemy

Я передаю в функцию *update* список из словарей, чтобы обновить записи. Вылезает ошибка, что не поддерживается обновление сразу нескольких записей. Как сделать чтобы за раз все обновилось, что мне нужно. Через цикл только если обновлять по отдельности каждую запись в БД?

```
await self.audio_dal.update(user_id=user_id, audio_list=audio_list)
```

```
async def update(self, user_id: int, audio_list: tuple[dict]) -> None:
    query = update(AudioFile).where(AudioFile.user_id == user_id).values(audio_list)

    await self.session.execute(query)
    await self.session.commit()
```

Ошибка:

```
File "c:path\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\dml.py", line 247, in _no_multi_values_supported
    raise exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: UPDATE construct does not support multiple parameter sets.
```

Answer (score 0):

Допустим есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE audio_file (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    audio_list VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Заполняем тестовыми данными

```
(1, 1, 'audio1')
(2, 2, 'audio2')
(3, 3, 'audio3')
```

Создаем временную таблицу например

```
CREATE TABLE new_data (
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    audio_list VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)
```

Заполняем значениями словарей

```
data = [{'user_id': 2, 'audio_list': 'audio222'},
        {'user_id': 3, 'audio_list': 'audio333'}]
```

Соединяем основную таблицу и временную и обновляем данные

```
update_tbl = (
            update(audio_file).
            where(audio_file.c.user_id == new_data.c.user_id).
            values(audio_list=new_data.c.audio_list)
        )
```

Получается

```
(1, 1, 'audio1')
(2, 2, 'audio222')
(3, 3, 'audio333')
```

Полный текст

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, insert, update,select
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect

# Создание движка базы данных
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///audio.db', echo=True)

# Создание метаданных
metadata = MetaData()

# Определение таблицы
audio_file = Table('audio_file', metadata,
                   Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                   Column('user_id', Integer, nullable=False),
                   Column('audio_list', String(255), nullable=False),
                   )

# Создание таблицы
# Создаем инспектор для проверки существования таблицы
inspector = inspect(engine)

# Проверяем, существует ли таблица
if audio_file.name in inspector.get_table_names():
    # Если таблица существует, удаляем и создаем ее
    audio_file.drop(bind=engine)
    audio_file.create(bind=engine)
else:
    audio_file.create(bind=engine)


# Вставка данных в таблицу
with engine.connect() as connection:
    with connection.begin():
        data = [{'user_id': 1, 'audio_list': 'audio1'},
                {'user_id': 2, 'audio_list': 'audio2'},
                {'user_id': 3, 'audio_list': 'audio3'}]
        connection.execute(insert(audio_file), data)
        result=connection.execute(select(audio_file))
for el in result:
    print(el)

# Создание временной таблицы с новыми данными
metadata = MetaData()
new_data = Table('new_data', metadata,
                 Column('user_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                 Column('audio_list', String(255), nullable=False),
                 )
if new_data.name  in inspector.get_table_names():
    # Если таблицa существует, удаляем и создаем ее
    new_data.drop(bind=engine)
    new_data.create(bind=engine)
else:
    new_data.create(bind=engine)

# Заполнение временной таблицы новыми данными
with engine.connect() as connection:
    with connection.begin():
        data = [{'user_id': 2, 'audio_list': 'audio222'},
                {'user_id': 3, 'audio_list': 'audio333'}]
        connection.execute(insert(new_data), data)

# Обновление таблицы audio_file данными из временной таблицы
with engine.connect() as connection:
    with connection.begin():
        update_tbl = (
            update(audio_file).
            where(audio_file.c.user_id == new_data.c.user_id).
            values(audio_list=new_data.c.audio_list)
        )
        connection.execute(update_tbl)
        result = connection.execute(select(audio_file))
        for el in result:
            print(el)
#Можно тут временную таблицу new_data удалить
```